# Make It Make Sense. Code Not Detecting a Session Is Active

Tags: php, session, directory

This is the weirdest thing, and I do no know why it's not working. On this webpage, it's supposed to be displaying the content only if the person is signed in. I programmed the entire thing on my computer locally using Xampp. I uploaded it to the server because it appeared to be working correctly. On the live server it for some reason is not detecting a session. For troubleshooting purposes, I echoed the session_status function. It said a session was active, but the rest of the code wasn't. I had another idea. I copied the code from an entire page on a different directory at the same level that worked perfectly and copied it to this page. I uploaded it to the server and suddenly an entire page of code that was working perfectly in another folder stopped working. So basically I've determined that a session is being started but not being detected by the lines of code that matter. I also tried deleting the folder from the online server and reuploading it, which didn't fix the problem. So....why would just this specific folder not want to be allowing the code to work correctly? Note that I've also checked every single other file in this particular folder. Not a single one wants to recognize a session.

This is the opening code at the start of the file that connects to the database, detects that a session is ongoing, and grabs additional info based on the info stored in the session.

```
<?php
include '../master-pages/db_connect.php';
session_start();
$email = "";
$errors = array();
$user_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$grab_session_info = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$user_email'";
$run_info = mysqli_query($conn, $grab_session_info);
if($run_info){
        $session_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_info);
        $user_name = $session_info['name'];
        $user_id = $session_info['user_id'];
        $account_type = $session_info['account_type'];
        $status = $session_info['status'];
}
?>
```

Further down, there is a line of code that detects whether or not someone is logged in and displays an additional navigation bar whether the aforementioned is true or false.

```
<?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || !empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
                include '../master-pages/private-nav.php';
            } else {
                
            }
            ?>
```

I've done quite a bit of troubleshooting as stated above. Checked to see if a session is in fact being set, seeing if a code that is very perfectly well in another folder works in this directory. Reuploading that entire folder in case something got, for lack of a better word, corrupted upon upload. I've got nothing, so I turn to this community.

Here in the part of the unique session data that it IS successfully pulling. It pulls the username from the email that is logged in.

```
<div id="login-and-register-wrap">
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['$email']) || !empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
                echo 'Welcome, ' .$user_name;
            } else {
                echo '<div id="login-and-register-divider">';
                echo '<a href="register.php">&#9998;Register</a>';
                echo '<a href="login.php">&#128274;Log In</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
</div>
```

This is why I am so confused as to why it's successfully grabbing the username because the user is logged, but not displaying the private navigation menu.

Comment: Have you checked the php error log file on the server for warnings or errors?

Comment: Given the above code, how do you know the session is not working? There are no debug statements here so it is hard to know where your code goes astray. Also session variables used directly in the sql do open up possibilities for sql injection - always use a prepared statement instead of embedding variables in sql like that

Comment: I have checked the error log, yes, and no errors are being reported. As for how I know a session is being set. I used the function session_status() to check to see if a session was being set. The output was 2, meaning a session was active.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you're assigning a value to `$_SESSION['email']`.

> As for how I know a session is being set. I used the function
> session_status() to check to see if a session was being set. The
> output was 2, meaning a session was active.

A session can be active, but at least according to your provided code, there's nowhere where you are assigning a value to your `email` session variable. If the problem is in the following:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || !empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
    include '../master-pages/private-nav.php';
} else {
    // Do something else
}
?>
```

Then it's likely that `isset($_SESSION['email']` is returning false. Consider setting the value of your `email` session variable to something like `test@gmail.com` and then immediately printing that value, like follows, and tell us what the results are:

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = "test@gmail.com";
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) {
    echo $_SESSION['email'];
}
```

Also, your code is wide open for SQL Injection:

```php
$grab_session_info = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$user_email'";
$run_info = mysqli_query($conn, $grab_session_info);
```

Consider using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` functions or even PDO. Here's an example of a query you can make with bind params:

```php
// Create your query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?;';
/* Create your bind variables--keep in mind,
the mysqli_stmt_bind_param() function CANNOT take raw values,
they MUST be variables so set them beforehand! */
$fetch_data_from_email = 'test@gmail.com';

function selectMyUser($conn, $sql, $param_types, ...$bind_vars) {
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn)
        or die('Your error here');
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)
        or die('Your error here');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $param_types ...$bind_vars)
        or die('Your error here');
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)
        or die('Your error here');
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)
        or die('Your error here');
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt)
        or die('Your error here');

    return $result;
}

// Retrieve your data and do something with it:

// The following will only pull the first valid record:
$res = selectMyUser($conn, $sql, 's', $fetch_data_from_email);
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    // If a record exists
    $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo $record['user_id'];
} else {
    // If a record doesn't exist
    echo 'Sorry, but a user with the email '.$fetch_data_from_email.' doesn\'t exist.';
}
```

The `'s'` for the `$param_types` indicates that the `$bind_var` for that corresponding type is a `string`. For example, `'i'` would be for an integer. You can find more about this [here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Using the code that you provided did display the email that I inputted. So why is the session not being set on this page when it's being set on others with the same code?

Comment: It is successfully displaying the name of the logged-in user at the top of the page, but won't recognize a session to display the private navigation.

Comment: Can you update your code to what it is currently, where the issue is?

Comment: Code above has been updated to reflect the session information that it's having no trouble retrieving.

Comment: @user21242428 I honestly think you need to fix the extreme security issues with your code before worrying about why this won't work. The code looks like it *should* work, but either something is missing that you're not giving us or something else. For one, I'd look in to using a user ID to grab user data like you're doing--a unique identifier of the user, rather than the user's email address. Second, you seriously need to fix your SQL stuff. It's prone to SQL Injection and you're using deprecated functions to write it.

Comment: There is just too many other things wrong to worry about before you worry about why the session data isn't working as you'd expect it to and displaying the section of the navbar you want.